# Align images WITH caption with a max-height of container

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

I am looking for a **css-only solution**.

I have illustrated my problem in the image below.

- Black: Parent container with a percentage height
- White: My image container having this height as his max-height
- Red: image itself, resizing proportionally and centering vertically
- Black and grey text: Caption below, sticking at the bottom left corner of the image in **ANY** variant shown below

[image: Goal]

Main problem for me is, letting the text wrap, if it's wider than the image. This was achieved with flexbox, but it's not working the way I want.

Anyone out there having the same problem or may there be someone who can help?

I am aware of many image aligning techniques and that I can solve my problem with JS, but I am looking for a CSS-only-solution.

**edit:** I should note, that these are 3 different images.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dazlious/so9o8p6t/)!

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.other-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #efefef;
}
.content-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
}
.scrollable-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
figure {
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
figcaption {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.credit {
  display: block;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="other-content">
    OTHER CONTENT HERE
  </div>
  <div class="content-container">

    <div class="scrollable-content">

      <figure class="img-container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/993x993/db0000/fff" alt="Lorem ipsum" />
        <figcaption class="caption">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
          <span class="credit">At vero eos et accusam</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure class="img-container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/993x200/db0000/fff" alt="Lorem ipsum" />
        <figcaption class="caption">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
          <span class="credit">At vero eos et accusam</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure class="img-container">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x993/db0000/fff" alt="Lorem ipsum" />
        <figcaption class="caption">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
          <span class="credit">At vero eos et accusam</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A quick google search turned up [**several CSS solutions**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20making%20figcaption%20same%20width%20as%20image).

Comment: @Michael_B: I am aware of these solutions. They are not providing a max-height for the image. Are you able to get my code working with any of these solutions? I tested all methods on first 3 result pages

Comment: Consider setting the `figure` element to `flex-direction: column`, which will vertically stack the image and caption. Then manage of the width of the flex container. (And reverse the values in `justify-content` and `align-items`.)

Comment: @Michael_B: Updated my example. Was my fault, I tried so much, that I missed to add correct values. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dazlious/so9o8p6t/11/) should work now. But caption runs out of box at bottom and caption is not aligned with image

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I was misunderstanding part of your question. All in all, I'm not sure how to confine the caption to the width of the image without JS.  I'll come back to this question after work.

Comment: Okay. Looking forward ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sven from http://maddesigns.de had the answer. Not the ultimate one, but a good answer:

http://codepen.io/maddesigns/pen/ZWdQjM

I just needed to add

```
height: auto;
max-height: 100%;
```

to the figure-element, to fit perfectly.

Unfortunately in this solution it is not possible to align the caption to fit the start of the image, BUT in my case, that is acceptable.